# How to compare all items in std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdmap, c++98

I'd like to compare all values in my `std::map` with each other.

I'm stuck with: for linear containers, like vector, I'd loop over indices `i=1; v[i].isUniform(v[i-1])`. But I can't do this with maps. I'm looking forward to hear clever ideas.

Here is some pseudocode of what I want to accomplish:

```cpp
class MyData
{
public:
    bool isUniform(const MyData& other) const
    {
        return this->speed == other.speed && this->ban == other.ban;
    }

private:
    bool ban;
    int  speed;
}

std::map<int, MyData> myMap;

bool allUniform = true;
for(item_1, item_2 : myMap) // how to implement this?
{
    if(!item_1.isUniform(item_2))
    {
        allUniform = false;
    }
}
```

What is the most elegant (readable and efficient) way to do that?

Comment: What does `isUniform` actually do? There may be a clever way to check the whole map without making O(n^2) comparisons like you're thinking.

Comment: What do you mean by "*compare all values with each other*"? Check if all values are the same? Pairwise compare each value with each other value (N*N)? Or something else?

Comment: Have you considered two for loops? `for(item_1 : myMap) {for(item_2 : myMap) {...}}`

Comment: Added more details about `isUniform()`. It essentially only checks some (not all) members on equality.

Comment: if you only want to compare some items, first take out those items and put them in a separate map. Then use `std::all_of` or any of the excellent solutions given below on that map.

Comment: `for(item_1, item_2 : myMap)` also wouldnt work for a vector, but a ranged based loop that works for a vector needs only very minor modification to be fine for a map also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(item_1, item_2 : myMap) // how to implement this?
```

But if they're all equal to each other (assuming `isUniform` is transitive and symmetric), that's the same as saying they're all equal to the first element. So, you can just compare each element to the first.

Naively, we get:

```
bool allUniform(std::map<int, MyData> const &m)
{
    if (m.empty()) return true; // or whatever makes sense for you

    auto first = m.begin();
    for (auto current = m.begin(); ++current != m.end(); )
    {
        if (!first->second.isUniform(current->second))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can simplify this if you don't mind comparing the first element to itself, because really most of the complexity is just avoiding that.

It'd probably be even better to use [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) as below, or the `std::all_of` solution in the other answer.

```
bool allUniform(std::map<int, MyData> const &m)
{
    auto first_non_uniform =
        std::adjacent_find(
            m.begin(), m.end(),
            [](auto left, auto right)
            {
                return !(left->second.isUniform(right->second));
            }
           );

    return first_non_uniform == m.end();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) for this with a lambda.  That would look like

```
bool allUniform = std::all_of(std::next(myMap.begin()), 
                              myMap.end(), 
                              [&myMap](const auto& pair)
                              { return myMap.begin()->second.isUniform(pair.second); });
```

This goes from `[1, N)` and calls `isUniform` againt each of those elements against the first.  `all_of` also short circuts so as soon as you have a non-uniform result it will end.

Answer (score 3):

Is isUniform() transitive? That is, does it follow this rule for any 3 MyData objects:

```
 isUniform(A, B) && isUniform(B, C) == isUniform(A, C)
```

If so, then you only need O(n) comparisons. Here is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class MyData {
public:
    int value;
    MyData(int _value) : value(_value) {}

    bool isUniform(const MyData &obj) const { return value == obj.value; }

    static void checkMap(map<int, MyData> myMap) {
         bool allUniform = true;
         MyData * firstItem = nullptr;

         for (auto it = myMap.begin(); allUniform && it != myMap.end(); ++it) {
             if (firstItem == nullptr) {
                  firstItem = &it->second;
             }
             else {
                  allUniform = firstItem->isUniform(it->second);
             }
         }

         cout << "All Uniform: " << (allUniform ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
    }
};

int main(int, char **) {
    map<int, MyData> map1;
    map<int, MyData> map2;
    MyData a1(1);
    MyData b1(1);
    MyData b2(2);
    MyData c1(1);

    // Should be uniform
    map1.insert(std::pair<int, MyData>(1, a1));
    map1.insert(std::pair<int, MyData>(2, b1));
    map1.insert(std::pair<int, MyData>(3, c1));
    MyData::checkMap(map1);

    // Should not be uniform
    map2.insert(std::pair<int, MyData>(1, a1));
    map2.insert(std::pair<int, MyData>(2, b2));
    map2.insert(std::pair<int, MyData>(3, c1));
    MyData::checkMap(map2);

    return 0;
}
```

With this output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x Foo.cpp -o Foo && Foo
All Uniform: Yes
All Uniform: No
```

Comment: Yes, or just use [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Comment: The need for transitivity of `isUniform` is a very good point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard algorithm `std::adjacent_find`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include<algorithm>

class MyData
{
public:
    MyData( bool ban, int speed ) : ban( ban ), speed( speed )
    {
    }

    bool isUniform(const MyData& other) const
    {
        return this->speed == other.speed && this->ban == other.ban;
    }

private:
    bool ban;
    int  speed;
};



int main() 
{
    std::map<int, MyData> myMap =
    {
        { 1, { true, 100 } }, { 2, { true, 100 } }, { 3, { true, 100 } }    
    };

    auto it = std::adjacent_find( std::begin( myMap ), std::end( myMap ),
                                  []( const auto &p1, const auto &p2 ) 
                                  {
                                    return not p1.second.isUniform( p2.second );
                                  } );

    bool allUniform = it == std::end( myMap );

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << allUniform << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare all elements in a collection to the first one:

```
template<class M, class F>
bool allEqual( M const& m, F&& f ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto b = begin(m);
  auto e = end(m);
  if (b == e) return true;
  for (auto it = std::next(b); it != e; ++it)
    if (!f( *b, *it))
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

compare all elements pairwise:

```
template<class M, class F>
bool pairwiseCompare( M const& m, F&& f ) {
  for (auto&& a:m)
    for (auto&& b:m)
    {
      if (std::addressof(a) == std::addressof(b))
        continue;
      if (!f(a,b))
        return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

this won't work on pseudo-containers like `std::vector<bool>`; well, it sort of will, but it will wastefully self-compare elements.